# Show virtual Keyboard when bluetooth keyboard connected?

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

I am building system for my company that use of a bluetooth RFID reader.
The problem is we cannot show the keyboard when the reader is connecting unless we turn it off.

But I saw this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uRlIw5H0wE&feature=related

And I know we can modify the reader to temperately show the keyboard. 
(Just like the button on Apple iOS keyboard)
[image: Media Key of toggle keyboard]

We can ask the provider to taylor-made the reader. So we want to add a physical button on it.

Do anyone know the keycode of that button?
Can it be done just to add a button to send a keycode event???

Answer (score 4):

The button that needs to be pressed is the eject button that's on a mac keyboard. I don't know what the key code is or even if you can send it. But I do know it is the eject button.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS keyboard gets hidden when a bluetooth or some other physical keyboard gets connected.
I think that the button is causing the Bluetooth HID-keyboard profile to disconnect at the scanner (which in-turn enables the iOS keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I have added details on how to show both bluetooth keyboard(using HID profile) and device virtual keyboard here [I want to force keyboard on with bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418790/i-want-to-force-keyboard-on-with-bluetooth-device) please check if it helps.