# Force software keyboard on iOS 10

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard

Is there any way anyone knows of to force the onscreen software keyboard in iOS when a Bluetooth HID device (like a barcode scanner) is active?

There are a few ancient questions on SO, but most work by manually adjusting the frame of the keyboard view, and that method no longer appears to work as of iOS 8.

Strangely there doesn't seem to be any information on how to do this post iOS 8. Is it just impossible?

See:

[Show iPhone soft keyboard even though a hardware keyboard is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Force on screen keyboard to show when bluetooth keyboard connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290417/force-on-screen-keyboard-to-show-when-bluetooth-keyboard-connected)

[Default keyboard is not coming when Barcode Scanner Device is Connected by Bluetooth in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437658/default-keyboard-is-not-coming-when-barcode-scanner-device-is-connected-by-bluet)

[Bluetooth HID Device & iOS textFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412649/bluetooth-hid-device-ios-textfields/7473886)

[Show virtual Keyboard when bluetooth keyboard connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927581/show-virtual-keyboard-when-bluetooth-keyboard-connected)

Comment: Sometimes Apple really frustrates me....

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: @EminIsrafiliOS Sadly no. I came to the conclusion it’s impossible now.